# What is the Minimum Setup Needed for Setting-up XDG Directories ($XDG_RUNTIME_DIR etc.)?

Tags: systemd, environment-variables, pam, xdg, xdg-base-directory

**I'm in a setup (20.04) that is basically headless (a solaris zone, but we could probably consider it analogous to any server sort of setup), and as such, I don't have any graphical environment installed already.**

When I log in (via SSH or `zlogin`), my $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR and friends are not set. I was wondering, what is the minimum setup I need to perform, to have these managed automatically by the system? I have read that the directories should be managed by PAM's systemd module, and so have installed `libpam-systemd`, to no avail.

There's plenty online regarding the setup of these directories, but much relates to graphical environments or sudo for example, where the root cause is different.

**Is there a package I need to install, or some minimum configuration to perform, to ensure that the XDG directories are set up and exported in the environment automatically, without resorting to installing some other large set of software (e.g. X) that will have it set up as a side effect, and without writing a script manually?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems my problem was actually related to a failure during boot of some systemd units that didn't show any other side-effects and wasn't picked up due to the nature this container was deployed. As such this has now resolved itself and so I assume that the `libpam-systemd` package is in fact all that is required.

Comment: Thank you for sharing with us your solution and contributing to the community. It seems like you've answered twice here during your solution process.. If this information is important to the solution process, please edit your accepted answer and add it, while removing your other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems as simple as a package called [xdg-user-dirs](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/xdg-user-dirs). Can't yet boot up the system in question and install this to verify but I imagine I can mark this as resolved once I can.

EDIT: This in fact sets up the expected user directories in the desktop metaphor, like Documents and Downloads. Admittedly I brushed over the man page and so this wasn't really relevant to the problem at hand.